# Failed to send join request to master ElasticSearch on AWS EC2 owned cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I am trying to build a cluster of 3 EC2 instances (I do not want to use the ElasticSearch service of amazon) and after installing the software and configuring it in all three instances I encounter the problem that they do not communicate with each other.

- I’m working with ES 5.5.1 on instances with Ubuntu 16.04
- All nodes are up and running
- All nodes has a Security Groupof AWS with permissions for all traffic between nodes (all ports)
- Internal firewall on very machine white list for every node

Master

```
cluster.name: excelle
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
node.master: true
path.data: /srv/data
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 172.31.MAS.TER
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.31.MAS.TER", "172.31.NODE.TWO", "172.31.NODE.THREE"]
```

Node two

```
cluster.name: excelle
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
node.master: false
path.data: /srv/data
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 172.31.NODE.TWO
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.31.MAS.TER", "172.31.NODE.TWO", "172.31.NODE.THREE"]
```

Node 3

```
cluster.name: excelle
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
node.master: false
path.data: /srv/data
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 172.31.NODE.THREE
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.31.MAS.TER", "172.31.NODE.TWO", "172.31.NODE.THREE"]
```

But on logs, on node 3 for exmple...

```
[2017-08-15T11:01:41,241][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [es03] failed to send join request to master [{esmaster}{scquEEaETDKMKLHzZvEHZQ}{NdLtMUXtT7WXnv1a4uHWqQ}{172.31.44.107}{172.31.44.107:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[esmaster][172.31.44.107:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[es03][172.31.18.76:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: IOException[connection timed out: 172.31.18.76/172.31.18.76:9300]; ]
```

I testing connection from node 3 to master not problem (for network question)

```
telnet 172.31.MAS.TER 9300
Trying 172.31.MAS.TER...
Connected to 172.31.MAS.TER.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

What it's wrong? Any idea?

Comment: I really wish there was an answer posted to this. I am having exactly the same issue. The only difference is I am connecting 3 master only nodes in a cluster.I want to use this via SpotInst. 8 spotinst data-only nodes connected to 1 AWS master worked fine.

Comment: Too older post. On my case, was other the problem. Problem was about a mistake on config file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to this posted on [ElasticSearch](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-doesn-t-start-status-1-failure-tls-x-pack/123498/15)

The gem was from manst:
"solution for this error (you must deleted contents of data folder(/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0) and restarted both the servers ):"

I deleted the nodes folder from each of my SpotInst instances and rebooted. My 3 ES distributed master-only nodes all came online. My 8 data-only nodes have connected automatically without any issue.